# "Co-worker" equivalent for "volunteer"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

**Question:** What is a term that can be used to describe someone who volunteers with you? Is "co-volunteer" an accepted term?

**Elaboration:** This question was brought to my attention when writing down references for a job application. The field, "relationship to reference," made me realize that I didn't know of and couldn't find a term that is similar to a "worker's co-worker." Since I couldn't find validation for the term "co-volunteer," I needed to ask this question.

**Note:** If this is a duplicate or posted in the wrong place, please point me in the right direction. I was unable to find this anywhere.

Comment: *Co-volunteer* may not be a widely used term, but its intended meaning would be immediately understood by almost everyone. As it is very apt for your purposes, there is probably no need to look for another one.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Regarding the application's question, I just used co-worker. However, for the term "volunteer" itself, is there an equivalent term that essentially means "co-volunteer"? It seems like "co-volunteer" is the obvious answer, but I was not able to find validation for that term.

Comment: @jsw29 I figured as much but wasn't able to find any credible information on the use of it. So are you suggesting it is considered an accepted term in today's world?

Comment: I am saying that *co-* is an accepted prefix and that it is acceptable to attach it to a word like *volunteer*, without waiting for some authority to specifically recognise *co-volunteer* as an accepted term.

Comment: @jsw29 Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I quite like the idea that a "co-volunteer" is the voluntary equivalent of a co-worker. However I think "fellow volunteer" is more widely used in practice.

Comment: Are you doing volunteer work? Then you are a worker. Those working with you are co-workers. There is no implication of employment arrangement there.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase I would recommend is "fellow volunteer". You can't go wrong with it; it's two well-established words. Here's an example:

> [Getting to Know Your Fellow Volunteers](https://www.vergemagazine.com/study-abroad/blogs/1590-getting-to-know-your-fellow-volunteers.html)

Alternatively, there are some people who use "covolunteer" or "co-volunteer" (h/t [jsw29](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/282363/jsw29)):

> Both Carly and her covolunteer from Virginia are kitchen-challenged—even though the covolunteer has already worked there for seven weeks. — [Ecuadorothy](https://books.google.com/books?id=GSoOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22covolunteer%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ_J_SzJb0AhUdqHIEHTRDDgAQ6AF6BAgMEAM)

> Like Mimi's covolunteer at the homeless shelter, Leticia had perceived CAPS and the Northtowners as racially divisive — [Us Versus Them: Race, Crime, and Gentrification in Chicago](https://books.google.com/books?id=h5XHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA121&dq=%22covolunteer%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ_J_SzJb0AhUdqHIEHTRDDgAQ6AF6BAgFEAM)

Answer (score 0):

I volunteered at the library in the local studies centre. There were quite a few volunteers who worked various short periods alongside paid staff. It became necessary to refer to volunteer colleagues to distinguish from staff colleagues. As far as the public were concerned, we were all staff and, other than different coloured lanyards, would not know the difference.

Answer (score -1):

I would use
[WORKMATE](https://www.lexico.com/definition/workmate) -
"A person with whom one works".